# DeviceOrientation API not working on Cordova/Android

Tags: android, cordova, device-orientation

I have a Cordova app, which I'm building for both iOS and Android. I'm using the HTML5 DeviceOrientation API (https://w3c.github.io/deviceorientation/) to obtain the device's orientation.

I install an event listener for "deviceorientation", and then process the event.alpha/beta/gamma values to determine orientation.

This works fine on iOS, but on Android it doesn't work. On Android, the "deviceorientation" event occurs only once, and the alpha/beta/gamma values are all null. Changing orientation after that does not result in any new events.

Has anyone experienced this? Any pointers on how I can debug?

Comment: So, I've found that this is only an issue with the Samsung J3 that I was using to test. I tried on other Android phones (at least the Pixel), and it worked fine. Anyone know why the J3 is different? Is it possible that it does not have accelerators?

Answer (score 1):

I ran to the same problem last year... Finally I found a forum topic where I read that the J3 doesn't have a real compass.